# How to get types for expo-sqlite?

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, typescript-typings

In version 33 of the expo sdk, sqlite got moved to it's own package, expo-sqlite, and now I can't get the types to load.

Instead of

```
import {SQLite} from 'expo';
```

I have

```
import {SQLite} from 'expo-sqlite';
```

But the types are not getting loaded.

I get the following type error:

```
Cannot find namespace 'SQLite'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types were missing in expo-sqlite package. I opened up an issue on Expo's GitHub page, and the problem has been resolved.

GitHub issue: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5264

Github pull request: https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/5544

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to have downloaded the module. Install the module and apply it.

```
npm install expo-sqlite
```

Comment: I have the module installed. The code runs, it just isn't getting typed correctly

Comment: @Daniel You can try `npm install` The method shown in the flag hub shall be `npm`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and created a Type Declaration file which solved the issue for me.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html

I copied the declarations from this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/expo

This is the declaration https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/expo/v31/index.d.ts#L2467

My project now has an `expo-sqlite.d.ts` file in the `src` folder which looks like

```
declare module 'expo-sqlite' {
  export namespace SQLite {
    type Error = any;

    interface Database {
      transaction(
        callback: (transaction: Transaction) => any,
        error?: (error: Error) => any, // TODO def of error
        success?: () => any
      ): void;
    }

    interface Transaction {
      executeSql(
        sqlStatement: string,
        arguments?: string[] | number[],
        success?: (transaction: Transaction, resultSet: ResultSet) => any,
        error?: (transaction: Transaction, error: Error) => any
      ): void;
    }

    interface ResultSet {
      insertId: number;
      rowAffected: number;
      rows: {
        length: number;
        item: (index: number) => any;
        _array: HashMap[];
      };
    }

    function openDatabase(
      name:
        | string
        | {
            name: string;
            version?: string;
            description?: string;
            size?: number;
            callback?: () => any;
          },
      version?: string,
      description?: string,
      size?: number,
      callback?: () => any
    ): any;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is accessing the data from a SQLResultSetRowList, then
I would suggest you to define an interface like CustomResultset that extends SQLResultSetRowList.

For example:

```
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';

interface CustomResultSet extends SQLite.SQLResultSetRowList {
    _array: [],
}
```

This may not be the optimal solution, but you should be able to access the Data through the _array property without having type errors in your code.

Answer (score -2):

Run below command to install:

```
npx expo install expo-sqlite
```

And import in your project:

```
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';

const db = SQLite.openDatabase('DBName.db');
```

Setup database:

```
const setupDatabaseAsync = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql(
        'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, name TEXT);',
        [],
        (tx, success) => {
          resolve(success);
          console.log('SUCCESS IN SETUP DB');
        },
        (err) => {
          reject(err);
          console.log('ERROR IN SETUP DB');
        }
      );
    });
  });
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [expo-sqlite-orm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-sqlite-orm) if you don't want to write queries.